# How to average daily data to weekly data?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data like:

```
Date                        Value
01/05/2021 00:00
01/05/2021 00:15
01/05/2021 00:30
01/05/2021 00:45
01/05/2021 01:00
01/05/2021 01:15
01/05/2021 01:30
01/05/2021 01:45
01/05/2021 02:00
01/05/2021 02:15
01/05/2021 02:30
01/05/2021 02:45
01/05/2021 03:00
01/05/2021 03:15
01/05/2021 03:30
01/05/2021 03:45
01/05/2021 04:00
01/05/2021 04:15
01/05/2021 04:30
01/05/2021 04:45
01/05/2021 05:00
01/05/2021 05:15
01/05/2021 05:30
01/05/2021 05:45
01/05/2021 06:00
01/05/2021 06:15
01/05/2021 06:30
01/05/2021 06:45
01/05/2021 07:00
01/05/2021 07:15
01/05/2021 07:30
01/05/2021 07:45
01/05/2021 08:00
01/05/2021 08:15
01/05/2021 08:30
01/05/2021 08:45
01/05/2021 09:00
01/05/2021 09:15
01/05/2021 09:30
01/05/2021 09:45
01/05/2021 10:00
01/05/2021 10:15
01/05/2021 10:30
01/05/2021 10:45
01/05/2021 11:00
01/05/2021 11:15
01/05/2021 11:30
01/05/2021 11:45
01/05/2021 12:00
01/05/2021 12:15
01/05/2021 12:30
01/05/2021 12:45
01/05/2021 13:00
01/05/2021 13:15
01/05/2021 13:30
01/05/2021 13:45
01/05/2021 14:00
01/05/2021 14:15
01/05/2021 14:30
01/05/2021 14:45
01/05/2021 15:00
01/05/2021 15:15
01/05/2021 15:30
01/05/2021 15:45
01/05/2021 16:00
01/05/2021 16:15
01/05/2021 16:30
01/05/2021 16:45
01/05/2021 17:00
01/05/2021 17:15
01/05/2021 17:30
01/05/2021 17:45
01/05/2021 18:00
01/05/2021 18:15
01/05/2021 18:30
01/05/2021 18:45
01/05/2021 19:00
01/05/2021 19:15
01/05/2021 19:30
01/05/2021 19:45
01/05/2021 20:00
01/05/2021 20:15
01/05/2021 20:30
01/05/2021 20:45
01/05/2021 21:00
01/05/2021 21:15
01/05/2021 21:30
01/05/2021 21:45
01/05/2021 22:00
01/05/2021 22:15
01/05/2021 22:30
01/05/2021 22:45
01/05/2021 23:00
01/05/2021 23:15
01/05/2021 23:30
01/05/2021 23:45
.....
31/12/2023 23.45
```

I am going to split every week of the data and averaging the AM and PM data per week in exactly month. I have no idea where to start. Thank you for your help before.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a series of 15-minute increments? To provide some more details of your data structure, please edit your question and include output from:  `dput(head(your_dataframe))` , While it will only include a few rows from a full dataset and includes samples from just one day, it will provide the actual data types of the columns you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Using `strftime` with `'%V'` for ISO-weeks (`'%U'` for US-weeks) in `aggregate`.

```
res <- with(df, aggregate(list(avg_value=value), list(week=strftime(date, '%V')), mean))
```

#### Gives

```
res
#    week avg_value
# 1    01 0.4779632
# 2    02 0.4876429
# 3    03 0.5007928
# 4    04 0.5126942
# 5    05 0.5094125
# 6    06 0.5118282
# 7    07 0.5129946
# 8    08 0.5136179
# 9    09 0.4892265
# 10   10 0.4842978
# 11   11 0.5024918
# 12   12 0.4717125
# 13   13 0.4898580
# 14   14 0.5018980
# 15   15 0.5028173
# 16   16 0.5124829
# 17   17 0.5061345
# 18   18 0.5034178
# 19   19 0.5117612
# 20   20 0.4810961
# 21   21 0.5160576
# 22   22 0.4785255
# 23   23 0.4644439
# 24   24 0.4979276
# 25   25 0.5063349
# 26   26 0.5007481
# 27   27 0.4939171
# 28   28 0.5022533
# 29   29 0.4872377
# 30   30 0.5010356
# 31   31 0.5046539
# 32   32 0.4880590
# 33   33 0.5104313
# 34   34 0.4859796
# 35   35 0.4933643
# 36   36 0.4989256
# 37   37 0.5126929
# 38   38 0.5149642
# 39   39 0.4840414
# 40   40 0.5021492
# 41   41 0.4988178
# 42   42 0.4766203
# 43   43 0.5051964
# 44   44 0.4923595
# 45   45 0.5222437
# 46   46 0.5240352
# 47   47 0.4997992
# 48   48 0.4968049
# 49   49 0.4817977
# 50   50 0.4919261
# 51   51 0.4943849
# 52   52 0.5172952
```

You can also use `aggregate(value ~ strftime(date, '%V'), df, mean)`, but column names are nicer with the `list` approach. **Note,** that date should be in `"Date"` or `"POSIX*"` format.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  date=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct('2022-01-01'), as.POSIXct('2022-12-31'), by='15 mins'),
  value=runif(34945)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my package timeplyr if you need summaries per rolling week.

You can install using the below code

```
remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(timeplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(time = dmy_hm(paste(Date, Value))) %>%
  mutate(Value = hm(Value)) %>%
  mutate(am_pm = if_else(hour(time) >= 0 & hour(time) < 12, 
                         "am", "pm")) %>%
  time_by(time, "weeks")

df2

# A tibble: 97 x 4
# Time:     time [2]
# By:       week
# Span:     2021-05-01 - 2023-12-30
   Date       Value     time                am_pm
   <chr>      <Period>  <dttm>              <chr>
 1 01/05/2021 0S        2021-05-01 00:00:00 am   
 2 01/05/2021 15M 0S    2021-05-01 00:00:00 am   
 3 01/05/2021 30M 0S    2021-05-01 00:00:00 am   
 4 01/05/2021 45M 0S    2021-05-01 00:00:00 am   
 5 01/05/2021 1H 0M 0S  2021-05-01 00:00:00 am   
 6 01/05/2021 1H 15M 0S 2021-05-01 00:00:00 am   
 7 01/05/2021 1H 30M 0S 2021-05-01 00:00:00 am   
 8 01/05/2021 1H 45M 0S 2021-05-01 00:00:00 am   
 9 01/05/2021 2H 0M 0S  2021-05-01 00:00:00 am   
10 01/05/2021 2H 15M 0S 2021-05-01 00:00:00 am   
# i 87 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

```
# Generate data
set.seed(4200)
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(value = rnorm(n()))

df2 %>%
  group_by(am_pm, .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   time [2]
  time                am_pm    mean
  <dttm>              <chr>   <dbl>
1 2021-05-01 00:00:00 am    0.00947
2 2021-05-01 00:00:00 pm    0.0363 
3 2023-12-30 00:00:00 pm    0.476
```

If you need full weeks supply `time_floor = TRUE` to `time_by()`.